# Экспортировал из Django БД в Excel. Как разбить файл Excel на страницы?

Tags: python, django, excel

Вопрос: экспортировал БД из Django в Excel. Получился один файл Excel со всей информацией. В таблице присутствуют одинаковые наименования полей. Как в Excel файле разбить на страницы, чтобы для каждого наименования поля была своя страница? Если наименование поля "Серия" разные, значит для каждого поля должна быть отдельная страница в файле Excel.

[image: exel файле разбить на страницы, что бы для каждого наименования поля была своя страницы?]

`views.py`:

```
def export_robots_xls(request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/ms-exel')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment;filename="robots.xls"'

    wb = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf-8')
    ws = wb.add_sheet('Robot')
    row_num = 0
    font_style = xlwt.XFStyle()
    font_style.font.bold = True
    columns = ['Серия', 'Модель', 'Версия']

    for col_num in range(len(columns)):
        ws.write(row_num, col_num, columns[col_num], font_style)

    font_style = xlwt.XFStyle()
    rows = Robot.objects.all().values_list('serial', 'model', 'version')

    for row in rows:
        row_num += 1
        
        for col_num in range(len(row)):
            ws.write(row_num, col_num, row[col_num], font_style)
            
    wb.save(response)
    return response
```